# My Swift MapKit Annotations Aren't Showing

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

My Swift MapKit annotations aren't showing unless I zoom all the way in. I am not sure why, and have done some research.

Here is my controller's code.

Annotations do in fact show, but only when you zoom all the way in. How can I show them when I am set to any region and zoom level?

```
//
//  DeliveryControllerMain.swift
//  CO19
//
//  Created by JJ Zapata on 3/20/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Jorge Zapata. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import CoreLocation
import FirebaseDatabase

class DeliveryControllerMain: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView : MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var posts = [ListObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.checkForLocationservices()
        self.getPlaces()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.getPlaces()
    }

    @IBAction func refrsh(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.getPlaces()
    }

    func getPlaces() {
        if CheckInternet.Connection() {
            posts.removeAll()

//            let mapAnno = MKPointAnnotation()
//            mapAnno.title = "asdf"
//            mapAnno.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 48.314084538662335, longitude: 11.55610970224152)
//            self.mapView.addAnnotation(mapAnno)

//            let allAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations
//            self.mapView.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)

            let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("Open")

            postRef.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                    let user = ListObject()
                    user.id = value["postID"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    user.title = value["postTitle"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    user.author = value["postAuthor"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    user.list = value["postList"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    user.date = value["postDate"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    user.long = value["postLong"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    user.status = value["postStatus"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    user.lat = value["postLat"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    self.posts.append(user)
                    // MAKE COORDINATES HERE
                    let london = MKPointAnnotation()
                    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(user.author!).child("name").observe(.value, with: { (data) in
                        let name : String = (data.value as? String)!
                        london.title = name
                        let long = Double(user.long!)
                        let lat = Double(user.lat!)
                        london.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(london)
                        print(user.lat!)
                        print(user.long!)
                    })

                }
                print(self.posts.count)
                print(self.posts)
                self.posts.reverse()
                // ACTION HERE
            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Connection", message: "Please Be Connected To Internet To Access Your LockIt Accounts", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func setupLocationanager() {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func checkAuthoritzation() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            self.centerViewOnUserLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            self.makeAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please Check Location Services Settings")
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted:
            self.makeAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please Check Location Services Settings")
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func checkForLocationservices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.setupLocationanager()
            self.checkAuthoritzation()
        } else {
            self.checkAuthoritzation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: center, latitudinalMeters: 1, longitudinalMeters: 1)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }

    func makeAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if let annotationTitle = view.annotation?.title {
            print("User tapped on annotation with title: \(annotationTitle!)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You’ve shared a ton of code unrelated to your problem. We don’t need any of this. We need to see the [`mapView(_:viewFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview) and/or your custom annotation view classes (if any). I’d suggest eliminating all of this unrelated code and show just the annotation and annotation view related code.

Comment: FWIW, it sounds like you haven’t set the annotation view’s `displayPriority` appropriately and/or you haven’t configured clustering correctly. But in the absence of any annotation view related code, it’s going to be hard for anyone to help you. So eliminate this unrelated code and add the annotation view related code...

Answer (score 0):

So, I’d suggest, at a minimum, to define annotation views for your annotations (and for clusters), setting the `displayPriority`. For example, if using `MKMarkerAnnotationView`:

```
class PointOfInterestClusterAnnotation: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        displayPriority = .required
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet {
            displayPriority = .required
        }
    }

}

class PointOfInterestAnnotation: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    static let clusteringIdentifier = "..."

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        displayPriority = .required
        clusteringIdentifier = PointOfInterestAnnotation.clusteringIdentifier
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet {
            clusteringIdentifier = PointOfInterestAnnotation.clusteringIdentifier
            displayPriority = .required
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, choose annotation names appropriate for your app. But hopefully this illustrates the idea.

And then in `viewDidLoad`, register these two annotation views:

```
mapView.register(PointOfInterestAnnotation.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
mapView.register(PointOfInterestClusterAnnotation.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```

(No [`mapView(_:viewFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview) is generally needed if targeting iOS 11 and later.)

If you do this, no annotation views should be disappearing when you zoom out, but rather you should enjoy clustering. And when you zoom back in, they should uncluster and reappear.